# Unity / C# - Is it possible to return the InputManager's forward, backward, left, right buttons?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controls

So in Unity, there's an "InputManager" which is set up to handle the controls. 
(e.g. Mouse, fire-buttons, left, right, etc.)

However, these controls can be changed/set manually, before actually playing the game.  And in my game, I want to include additional scripting when these buttons are held down or released.  But, I can't seem to find any information about how to return the Key (or KeyCode) of which button is assigned.

So for clarity, I'll give an example...
The default InputManager key for up is "W", and "Up-Arrow".  But if someone changes "Up" to say "U", before playing the game, I want my script to have events for pressing/releasing "U".

So my question is, is it possible to return the button(s) mapped to the InputManager?  Or how do you manually handle scripting events for pressing/releasing "forward", "backward", etc.?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I figured it out and will answer my own question.  (Kind of embarrassed by the simplicity, but posting anyways for anyone else who gets stumped, like I was.)

The answer is:

So instead of using Input.GetKey & Input.GetKeyDown (Like I was)

Using - Input.GetButton & Input.GetButtonDown, instead.

So the code would be as follows:

```
if (Input.GetButton("Vertical"))
{
    //your code
}
```

As where "Vertical" is the default name in InputManager for Up and Down.

Hope this helps someone else.